# Can Pending Intent request code be negative?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have searched all over internet but not found much help there. I am making an alarm application in which i am using pending intents with alarm  manager. I want to set two alarms based  on specific id of the sqlite database table. For the first alarm I  am setting pending intent request code as positive id, and for  the second intent I am setting pending intent request  code as negative id (-1 * id).
Here is the code

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, -1 *_id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Can _id  be negative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

usually `_id` is marked as `autoincrement`. Accordingly to the sqlite documentation, for [autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), if you don't insert explicitly a negative value, then the values generated for this column are always positive. `_id` could be negative if you explicitly insert a negative value.

> Can Pending Intent request code be negative?

the documentation says nothing about negative values. The method accepts an `int` value and, in java, all the primitive types are signed. So, we have to assume that the request code can assume negative values

Answer (score -1):

```
List<PendingIntent> plist;

void setReminder()

{
 plist = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Notify.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Timetableconfig.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, list.size(), alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    plist.add(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, toofix.getTimeInMillis() - 300000, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60*1000, plist.get(plist.size()-1));

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.